# Logical OR in regular expression for email

Tags: regex

Folks,

I had a basic question about regular expressions, I wanted to write a regular expression which matches * OR *@anything.com. The following works fine ***+@.+$** for email but I am not able to figure out how to do * OR ***+@.+$**.

Thank you

Comment: Something like `*+(@anything.com)?+$` maybe? The `?` matches zero or one occurrence of what's right before it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logical `OR` in regex is `|`, so literally, in your case:

```
\*|\*@.+$
```

But the regex above can be simplified to

```
\*(@.+$)?
```

Indeed, the `*` char must be present whatever, just the `@.+$` is optional (`?` means *"0 or 1 time"*).

You'll possibly need to use the `^` anchor, which means *"the beginning of the string"*:

```
^\*(@.+$)?
```

Comment: \*(@.+$)? works fine but it matches multiple occurrences of *, in both cases I want only one occurrence of *

Comment: @user1781472 Could you provide the way you're using it? A code snippet in the language you're using?

Comment: teststr = "****" if teststr.match(/\\*(@.+$)?/) puts "MATCH" end #this will match but I dont want it to match

Comment: 1.9.3p125 :080 > st = "\*\*"
 => "**" 
1.9.3p125 :081 > if st.match(/^\*(@.+$)?/)
1.9.3p125 :082?>   puts "MATCH"
1.9.3p125 :083?>   end
MATCH
 => nil

Comment: looks like something to do with the way regexp works with ruby

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? : 
[^@]*@.+$

It would match anything that isn't an "@" multiple times until the "@anything.com"

Comment: thanks for the quick response, just to clarify the only two things I want the regex to match is \\* OR \\*@.+$.

Comment: @user1781472 With `$`, you mean *the real dollar char*, or the end of the string?

Comment: with $ I mean end of string, so it should either match the value * OR it should match *@.+$

Comment: Sorry about the mistake. The regex I gave you matches : something@anything.com and @anything.com. I'm not sure to understand what you want to match? You can't match everything OR something else... Because something else is contained inside everything. Can you clarify please?